How to allow typing leading 0 in MUI-Date range picker and Date picker components?
MUI Date range picker and Date picker components does not allow us to type dates or months with leading 0. For an Example if a particular user wants to type 5th of June he/she may probably write like 05/06. However if the user write 0 as the first digit and 5 as the second digit on the component it does not update with 0. Although when we write 5 as the second digit it show the date as 05. The behavior is somewhat confusing because users might think typing does not working at the first glance. Really appreciate anyone can help me if you are overcome this matter.
To overcome this issue I tried many thing. There is a prop called inputField which only avalable in @mui/lab but when I am going to use that I saw that it was deprecated feature.
Other effective solution I found was using slot prop for custom configuration of the rendered output. It was success some far but does not fully resolve what I want, because it arise some errors like violating rendering components inside a component. (Here I am using @mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker)
Ex:
slots={{
              textField: ({ inputProps: { start, end } }) => (
                <Box display="flex" gap={2}>
                  <TextField
                    {...start}
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Start Date"
                    inputProps={{
                      ...start?.inputProps,
                      maxLength: 10, // Ensuring max length for date input
                    }}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    {...end}
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="End Date"
                    inputProps={{
                      ...end?.inputProps,
                      maxLength: 10, // Ensuring max length for date input
                    }}
                  />
                </Box>
              ),
            }}


I cannot re-produce your issue. Can you post the full code of DataRangePicker?
